# Functions as arguments to functions

Tags: python, function, arguments

I saw this example in a Python book, which showcases how to use a function as an argument to another function:

```
def diff2(f, x, h=1E-6):
    r = (f(x-h) - 2*f(x) + f(x+h))/float(h*h)
    return r

def g(t):
    return t**(-6)

t = 1.2
d2g = diff2(g, t)
print d2g
```

My question is, how does this script work without providing an argument to function g? The line in question is:

```
d2g = diff2(g,t)
```

Shouldn't it be done like:

```
d2g = diff2(g(t), t)
```

Comment: `g(t)` in your last line would tell `g` to execute with argument `t`, which is not what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`g` is passed as an argument to `diff2`.  In `diff2`, that argument is called `f`, so inside `diff2` the name `f` refers to the function `g`.  When `diff2` calls `f(x-h)` (and the other calls it does), it is calling `g`, and providing the argument.

In other words, when you do `diff2(g, t)`, you are telling `diff2` that `g` is the function to call.  The arguments to `g` are provided in `diff2`:

```
f(x-h) # calls g with x-h as the argument
f(x)   # calls g with x as the argument
f(x+h) # calls g with x+h as the argument
```

If you called `diff2(g(t), t)`, you would be passing the *result* of `g(1.2)` as the argument.  `g` would be called before calling `diff2`, and `diff2` would then fail when it tries to call `f`, because `f` would be a number (the value `g(1.2)`) instead of a function.

Comment: I have slightly revised my question. What confuses me is we never provide an argument to function g in the example above.

Comment: @marillion: As I wrote, you do.  You just don't call `g` in the line `diff2(g, t)`.  What you do is tell `diff2` what function to call, and `diff2` calls it, providing the arguments at that time.

Comment: I may be wrong but functions in python are first class objects.

Comment: @BrenBarn Thank you for the explanation, took me a while but I finally got it.

Answer (score 3):

The functions in question are rather random, and perhaps difficult to understand. Let's consider a simple example, a function `sum` which takes two numbers `a` and `b`, and returns their sum. Actually, we can easily define another function `prod`, which returns their product too.

```
def sum(a,b):
    return a + b

def prod(a,b):
    return a * b
```

Let's say we have another function `compute`, which takes as its arguments the operation (a function), and two operands (two numbers to call the function on). In `compute`, we call the given operation on the arguments.

```
def compute(fn, a, b):
    return fn(a, b)
```

We can `compute` different things. We can `compute` the `sum` of two numbers:

```
compute(sum, 1, 3)
```

We can `compute` the product of two numbers:

```
compute(prod, 1, 3)
```

Basically, without parentheses after the function name, we're not actually calling the function, it's just another *object* in the namespace (which happens to be a function which we can call). We don't call the function until inside of `compute`, when we do `fn(a,b)`.

Let's see what the console outputs look like:

```
>>> compute(sum,1,3)
4
>>> compute(prod,1,3)
3
>>> sum
<function sum at mem-address>
>>> prod
<function prod at mem-address>
>>> sum(1,2)
3
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the clear explanation. this: "we're not actually calling the function, it's just another object in the namespace" along with BrenBran's reply helped me a lot with understanding what is going on.